# Java Thread Id Creation Time

Tags: java, multithreading

I was wondering when does the Id of a thread in Java is created. Is it in the moment the instance is created or is it after is launched with the start method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When instantiated.

```
public Thread() {
   init(null, null, "Thread-" + nextThreadNum(), 0);
}

private void init(ThreadGroup g, Runnable target, String name, long stackSize) {
   ...
   /* Set thread ID */
   tid = nextThreadID();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is initialized on the `Thread` constructor.

Code snippet from implementation here:

```
/* Set thread ID */
tid = nextThreadID();
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of **instance creation**.

Answer (score 0):

From the source code id returned from Thread.getId() is initialized when Thread instance were created (i.e. in its constructor), regardless when this Thread instance is actually started.